# Measure precision of timer (e.g. Stopwatch/QueryPerformanceCounter)

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarking, stopwatch, microbenchmark

Given that the `Stopwatch` class in C# can use something like three different timers underneath e.g.

- System timer e.g. precision of approx `+-10 ms` depending on timer resolution that can be set with [`timeBeginPeriod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx) it can be approx `+-1 ms`.
- Time Stamp Counter (TSC) e.g. with a tick frequency of 2.5MHz or 1 tick = `400 ns` so ideally a precision of that.
- High Precision Event Timer (HPET) e.g. with a tick frequency of 25MHz or 1 tick = `40 ns` so ideally a precision of that.

how can we measure the observable precision of this? Precision being defined as

> Precision refers to the closeness of two or more measurements to each
>   other.

Now if the `Stopwatch` uses HPET does this mean we can use `Stopwatch` to get measurements of a precision equivalent to the frequency of the timer?

I don't think so, since this requires us to be able to use the timer with zero variance or a completely fixed overhead, which as far as I can tell is not true for `Stopwatch`. For example, when using HPET and calling:

```
var before_ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
var after_ticks = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
var diff_ticks = after_ticks - before_ticks;
```

then the diff will be say approx `100 ticks` or `4000 ns` and it will have some variance too.

So how could one experimentally measure the observable precision of the `Stopwatch`? So it supports all possible timer modes underneath.

My idea would be to search for the minimum number of ticks != 0, to first establish the overhead in ticks of the `Stopwatch` that is for system timer this would be 0 until e.g. `10ms` which is 10 * 1000 * 10 = 100,000 ticks since system timer has a tick resolution of `100ns`, but the precision is far from this. For HPET it will never be 0 since the overhead of calling `Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()` is higher than the frequency of the timer.

But this says nothing about how precise we can measure using the timer. My definition would be how small a difference in ticks we can measure reliably.

The search could be performed by measuring different number of iterations ala:

```
var before = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
{
    action(); // Calling a no-op delegate Action since this cannot be inlined
}
var after = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
```

First a lower bound could be found where all of say 10 of measurements for a given number of `iterations` yield a non-zero number of ticks, save these measurements in `long ticksLower[10]`. Then the closest possible number of iterations that yield tick difference that is always higher that any of the first 10 measurements could be found, save these in `long ticksUpper[10]`.

Worst case precision would then be the highest ticks in `ticksUpper` minus lowest ticks in `ticksLower`.

Does this sound reasonable?

Why do I want to know the observable precision of the `Stopwatch`? Because this can be used for determining the length of time you would need to measure for to get a certain level of precision of micro-benchmarking measurements. I.e. for 3 digit precision the length should be >1000 times the precision of the timer. Of course, one would measure multiple times with this length.

Comment: I'm consistently getting a 0 or 1 for `diff_ticks`. My `Stopwatch.Frequency` is `1948294`. What hardware/OS do you use?

Comment: By the way check the [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895.aspx) function (you'll have to P/Invoke it).

Comment: I agree with @LucasTrzesniewski. `diff_ticks` is 0 or 1, with about 85% zeros at a frequency of 2610117 running in release mode on an i7 920 at 2.66 GHz.

Comment: Run the test for 1000.0 / Stopwatch.Frequency seconds and you're guaranteed to get a thousand ticks.  However, you have to keep in mind that the clock is not that accurate, you can't measure less than 0.0156 seconds.  And that measuring elapsed time is too expensive, it affects the result too much.  So this can't work reliably, the only thing you can do is run action() up front several times to take a guestimate at how long it takes, then calculate *iterations*.  It doesn't have to be perfect.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski that just means you are using the TSC timer because you haven't enabled the HPET timer. You can enable by running "bcdedit /set useplatformclock true" and rebooting.

Comment: @HansPassant I do not think that is true, definitely not when the System timer is used. Getting a thousands ticks is not enough. Not when the precision of the ticks is worse than 1 tick. And yes, my plan was then to find the number of iterations that need to be performed for a given action() to be longer than the required precision. Why not less than 0.0156 seconds?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408.aspx#resolution__precision__accuracy__and_stability "Cases might exist where QueryPerformanceFrequency (QPC) doesn't return the actual frequency of the hardware tick generator. For example, in many cases, QPC returns the TSC frequency divided by 1024; and on Hyper-V, the performance counter frequency is always 10 MHz when the guest virtual machine runs under a hypervisor that implements the hypervisor version 1.0 interface. As a result, don't assume that QPC will return the precise TSC frequency."

Comment: BenchmarkDotNet makes pilot runs and has ad-hoc values for how long they run for a given measurement e.g. 200ms, but 200ms is a very long time when you have a HPET timer, for example, So I am trying to find the minimum iteration count by first determining the observable precision of the timer and using that to say the minimum amount of time a measurement should run over and thus the number of iterations, instead of some ad-hoc or rule of thumb. See: https://github.com/PerfDotNet/BenchmarkDotNet/blob/3c4410fbd8b61e6d4c44968f1d63d485b62c6990/BenchmarkDotNet/Running/MethodInvoker.cs#L107

Comment: I've recently stumbled upon this article that I think might set you in the right direction: http://aakinshin.net/en/blog/dotnet/legacyjitx86-and-first-method-call/

Comment: @harrydev, I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time, HPET support is a big challange. I think, that the only way to determine QPC overhead is a separated mincobenchmark. I'm going to implement this approach in BenchmarkDotNet soon.

Comment: @AndreyAkinshin I have been experimenting and thinking about this for some time and my conclusion is the "precision" can be determined by measuring say 10 x *unique* timestamps as fast as possible and taking the median of the differences between these. This will give the precision due to both tick resolution (e.g. system timer) and (due to latency in the case of HPET). This appears to be good enough. Then if 3 digit precision is desired you simply multiply by 1000x which can then be used to find the number of iterations during pilot run.

Answer (score 0):

The Stopwatch class exposes a [Frequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx) property that is the direct result of calling SafeNativeMethods.[QueryPerformanceFrequency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905.aspx). Here is an excerpt of the property page:

> The Frequency value depends on the resolution of the underlying timing
>   mechanism. If the installed hardware and operating system support a
>   high-resolution performance counter, then the Frequency value reflects
>   the frequency of that counter. Otherwise, the Frequency value is based
>   on the system timer frequency.

Comment: I thought you might, but you didn't mention it in your post and it seemed the most exact way of determining the precision of the underlying timer. StopWatch is a class to measure how much time elapsed from one point to another, though. The smallest time between two measurements - which is NOT the precision - depends on when you actually take the measurements and has little to do with the class that measures the time. The value of the time might be larger or smaller based on specific implementations, as well. Is there a larger purpose to your question? Maybe we should start with that.

Comment: That is exactly why I want to measure/estimate the precision of the timer, to be able to have a good basis for doing precise micro-benchmarking in the shortest possible time for example. This is not just for doing ad-hoc measurements but something ala BenchmarkDotNet, but they take the conservative route and run for a "long" time e.g. each measurement is for 1 second by finding number of iterations that give that time period for a given action that is being benchmarked.

Comment: Sorry, I might not really get what you want, because it sounds like you want to know how long it takes to give you the exact time, which is a bit circular. I would compute how long does it take to iterate an empty loop, how long it takes to iterate the same loop with GetTimeStamp and from there estimate how long it takes to execute GetTimeStamp, then maybe subtract that value from the measured time returned by the method. However, you have no idea how the compiler optimizes these calls.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'm not explaining myself very well ;) What you describe sounds like overhead, this is not what I am looking for. Basically I want to determine the precision with which one can make timer measurements, not the theoretical precision given by Frequency (which isn't true for system timer anyway), but the precision that is observable or repeatable...