# Why does adding a parallel for loop slow down the single threaded loop?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I am trying to compare the performance of single threaded vs parallel for in C#, when I stumbled upon this peculiar case:

Code # 1 (Single Threaded only)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var iterations = 1000000000;
    var sum = 0;

    var stp = new Stopwatch();
    stp.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        sum++;
    }
    stp.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Single Thread");
    Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Time Taken (ms): {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
}
```

Result

> Single Thread Sum: 1000000000 Time Taken (ms): 351

Code # 2 (Single threaded and Parallel together)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var iterations = 1000000000;
    var sum = 0;

    var stp = new Stopwatch();
    stp.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        sum++;
    }
    stp.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Single Thread");
    Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Time Taken (ms): {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

    sum = 0;
    stp.Reset();
    stp.Start();
    Parallel.For(0, iterations, i =>
    {
        sum++;
    });
    stp.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Parallel");
    Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Time Taken (ms): {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
}
```

Result

> Single Thread Sum: 1000000000 Time Taken (ms): 1865
>
> Parallel Sum: 275202313 Time Taken (ms): 5831

Why did the performance of the single threaded part change so drastically after adding the parallel part?

This difference:

> Code # 1
> Single Thread Sum: 1000000000 Time Taken (ms): 351
>
> Code # 2
> Single Thread Sum: 1000000000 Time Taken (ms): 1865
>
> 351 vs 1865 ms for the same piece of code?

Comment: Related: [Why is a parallel processing much slower for a first call in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47035547/why-is-a-parallel-processing-much-slower-for-a-first-call-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was the parallel version slower than the sequential version in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418493/why-was-the-parallel-version-slower-than-the-sequential-version-in-this-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IL generated for each of these is different. First let's look at the first example (without the parallel in the program, only including up to the `Stopwatch.Stop()`):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       121 (0x79)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init ([0] int32 iterations,
           [1] int32 sum,
           [2] class [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stp,
           [3] int32 i,
           [4] bool V_4)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4     0x3b9aca00  //Loads 10000000
  IL_0006:  stloc.0   //Store in the stack position 0
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.0  //Push 0 onto the stack as int32
  IL_0008:  stloc.1   //Pop a variable from stack into position 1
  IL_0009:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::.ctor()
  IL_000e:  stloc.2
  IL_000f:  ldloc.2
  IL_0010:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Start()
  IL_0015:  nop
  IL_0016:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0017:  stloc.3
  IL_0018:  br.s       IL_0024
  IL_001a:  nop        //Start of For Loop
  IL_001b:  ldloc.1
  IL_001c:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_001d:  add
  IL_001e:  stloc.1
  IL_001f:  nop
  IL_0020:  ldloc.3
  IL_0021:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0022:  add
  IL_0023:  stloc.3
  IL_0024:  ldloc.3
  IL_0025:  ldloc.0
  IL_0026:  clt
  IL_0028:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_002a:  ldloc.s    V_4
  IL_002c:  brtrue.s   IL_001a    //If true, branch back to start
  IL_002e:  ldloc.2
  IL_002f:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Stop()
```

It is relatively simple, I added a couple comments but really this is about as simple as it gets. Let's compare to the parallel version (again, just the for loop up until the stopwatch stop):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       257 (0x101)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] class Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0' 'CS$8__locals0',
           [1] int32 iterations,
           [2] class [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stp,
           [3] int32 i,
           [4] int32 V_4,
           [5] bool V_5)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0'::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4     0x3b9aca00
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldloc.0
  IL_000e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000f:  stfld      int32 Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0'::sum
  IL_0014:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::.ctor()
  IL_0019:  stloc.2
  IL_001a:  ldloc.2
  IL_001b:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Start()
  IL_0020:  nop
  IL_0021:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0022:  stloc.3
  IL_0023:  br.s       IL_003d
  IL_0025:  nop
  IL_0026:  ldloc.0
  IL_0027:  ldfld      int32 Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0'::sum
  IL_002c:  stloc.s    V_4
  IL_002e:  ldloc.0
  IL_002f:  ldloc.s    V_4
  IL_0031:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0032:  add
  IL_0033:  stfld      int32 Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0'::sum
  IL_0038:  nop
  IL_0039:  ldloc.3
  IL_003a:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_003b:  add
  IL_003c:  stloc.3
  IL_003d:  ldloc.3
  IL_003e:  ldloc.1
  IL_003f:  clt
  IL_0041:  stloc.s    V_5
  IL_0043:  ldloc.s    V_5
  IL_0045:  brtrue.s   IL_0025
  IL_0047:  ldloc.2
  IL_0048:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Stop()
```

Notice one thing? The `ldfld` and `stfld` calls? These are object model instructions instead of base instructions. What these are doing is storing and loading from fields instead of working directly on the stack. Those calls are more expensive. Why it compiled differently?

Well for one thing, parallizing means that all the threads need to have access to `sum`, so the compiler changes `sum` to be a class-level field instead of a local variable. This is a big difference, now it has to work with compiler generated fields instead of directly on the stack. Additionally you'll notice that the compiler also now creates an instance of the class:

`IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0'::.ctor()`

Which it uses just to access the `sum` field, so there is more overhead.

I believe if you changed the second example to use a separate field for `sum` (like `sum2`) it would behave closer to what you are expecting:

(Same example as the second, except using a different variable for the second sum):

```
var iterations = 1000000000;
var sum = 0;
var stp = new Stopwatch();
stp.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    sum++;
}
stp.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Single Thread");
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}");
Console.WriteLine($"Time Taken (ms): {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

var sum2 = 0;
stp.Reset();
stp.Start();
Parallel.For(0, iterations, x =>
{
    sum2++;
});
stp.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Parallel");
Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum2}");
Console.WriteLine($"Time Taken (ms): {stp.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

Console.ReadKey(true);
```

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       244 (0xf4)
  .maxstack  4
  .locals init ([0] class Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0' 'CS$8__locals0',
           [1] int32 iterations,
           [2] int32 sum,
           [3] class [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stp,
           [4] int32 i,
           [5] bool V_5)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Test.Program/'c__DisplayClass0_0'::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  nop
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4     0x3b9aca00
  IL_000c:  stloc.1
  IL_000d:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000e:  stloc.2
  IL_000f:  newobj     instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::.ctor()
  IL_0014:  stloc.3
  IL_0015:  ldloc.3
  IL_0016:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Start()
  IL_001b:  nop
  IL_001c:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_001d:  stloc.s    i
  IL_001f:  br.s       IL_002d
  IL_0021:  nop
  IL_0022:  ldloc.2
  IL_0023:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0024:  add
  IL_0025:  stloc.2
  IL_0026:  nop
  IL_0027:  ldloc.s    i
  IL_0029:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_002a:  add
  IL_002b:  stloc.s    i
  IL_002d:  ldloc.s    i
  IL_002f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0030:  clt
  IL_0032:  stloc.s    V_5
  IL_0034:  ldloc.s    V_5
  IL_0036:  brtrue.s   IL_0021
  IL_0038:  ldloc.3
  IL_0039:  callvirt   instance void [System]System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch::Stop()
```

Which is nearly identical to the original test, except some different locations and offsets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to 'warm' up your loop first. Try doing the first loop 10 times in a row and you will see that the time drops after the first iteration.

What you are seeing is probably the extra time to JIT the second half.

Although, even with a warm up loop there is still a difference between the two which could be as @Joel says due to additional checks being added for access across threads. You can check this out by changing the parallel loop to use its own variable 'sum2' and then the times seem about equal.

The answer may be as simple as the compiler chooses to optimize the first loop to use a register when it sees no parallel access.

BTW Take a look at benchmarkdotnet on nuget, it handles warming up and running multiple tests to get accurate test times.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to actually understand the question, instead of jumping to conclusions like everyone else seems to be.

Comment: The IL code generated for the single-threaded loop is significantly different between the programs.  I believe you are correct about the compiler choosing a different strategy due to the variable being shared across the loops.  Program 1 uses only registers.  Program 2 creates a variable on the stack.

Comment: It isn't JIT, see my answer, the problem is the parallel access to `sum` requiring the compiler to turn it into a class-level field instead of something on the stack locally. Accessing the field has a lot of overhead.

Answer (score -1):

The operations are not fully parallel. They require sharing a resource on the host thread (the `sum` variable). Therefore the parallel version has to do more work than the single threaded version because of the additional coordination required to safely access the shared resource.

Additionally, you're spawning a bunch of threads just to increment a single integer value. The work involved in spawning and queuing the thread is greater than the work of just incrementing the variable.

A better example would be if you had a collection like an array or List, and wanted to do a significant amount of work on each item in the collection. Then the collection could be divided among the available threads and each thread does more work than it cost to create it.

Comment: The performance of the parallel code is irrelevant.  The first part of the program is the exact same loop single-threaded loop as the first program.  The parallel loop is only started **after** the timer for the first loop completes.